# Scheduling of multiple goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

```golang
package main

import "fmt"


func square(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("[square] reading (4)")
    num := <-c
    fmt.Println("[square] calc (5)")
    c <- num * num
    fmt.Println("back from [square] (10)")
}

func cube(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("[cube] reading (3)")
    num := <-c
    fmt.Println("[cube] calc (11)")
    c <- num * num * num
    fmt.Println("back from [cube] (12)")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("[main] main() started (1)")

    squareChan := make(chan int)
    cubeChan := make(chan int)

    go square(squareChan)
    go cube(cubeChan)

    testNum := 3
    fmt.Println("[main] sent testNum to squareChan (2)")

    squareChan <- testNum

    fmt.Println("[main] resuming (6)")
    fmt.Println("[main] sent testNum to cubeChan (7)")

    cubeChan <- testNum // why doesn't block here?

    fmt.Println("[main] resuming (8)")
    fmt.Println("[main] reading from channels (9)")

    squareVal, cubeVal := <-squareChan, <-cubeChan
    fmt.Println("[main] waiting calculating (13)")

    fmt.Println("[main] results: ", squareVal, cubeVal)
    fmt.Println("[main] main() stopped")
}
```

output:

```
[main] main() started (1)
[main] sent testNum to squareChan (2)
[cube] reading (3)
[square] reading (4)
[square] calc (5)
[main] resuming (6)
[main] sent testNum to cubeChan (7)
[main] resuming (8)
[main] reading from channels (9)
back from [square] (10)
[cube] calc (11)
back from [cube] (12)
[main] waiting calculating (13)
[main] results:  9 27
[main] main() stopped
```

In the code given above, I think the `main()` routine should be blocked after `cubeChan <- testNum`, then `cube` routine should be scheduled, which means the output `[cube] calc (11)` ought to be prior to `[main] resuming (8)`. But after executing on Playground, I'm so confused by the output.

Could anyone tell me if I misunderstand anything?

Comment: `I think the main() routine should be blocked after cubeChan <- testNum` Why? There is no reason to.

Comment: @tkausl  In my opinion, cubeChan is a channel of capacity 0. sending an element to a full channel should cause blocking.

Comment: The other goroutine is blocked reading on the channel, so the send succeeds immediately.

Comment: but in the same case, why `[main] resuming (6)` is after `[square] calc (5)`, while `square()` is blocked reading on the channel squareChan.

Comment: Its blocked _writing_, because main isn't reading.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the main() routine should be blocked after cubeChan <- testNum

it does block, but at these:

```
squareVal, cubeVal := <-squareChan, <-cubeChan
                      ^             ^
```

if either `squareChan` or `cubeChan` doesn't receive any values in other routines, that line will become deadlock, modify `cube()` like below to see the effect:

```
func cube(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("[cube] reading (3)")
    _ = <-c
    fmt.Println("[cube] calc (11)")
    // c <- num * num * num
    fmt.Println("back from [cube] (12)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding con-current code.

But, channels only block flow if they have nothing to output or if they're full. And channels can only get full if you specify a size.

I also dont recommend using the same channel for input and output for a function

With your current method you could run into trouble here

```
cubeChan <- testNum 

fmt.Println("[main] resuming (8)")
fmt.Println("[main] reading from channels (9)")

squareVal, cubeVal := <-squareChan, <-cubeChan
```

If your cube function is too slow for any possible number of reasons, the testNum that you add onto the cubechan could be instantly taken off with this line here

```
squareVal, cubeVal := <-squareChan, <-cubeChan
```